# How to get the Publication Target of a current Page in C#?

Tags: 2009, c#

What I need is to have the Publication Target of a current Page.

With the following code I get the Publication Target where the Page is published, but now I need to ensure that this Publication Target is the same as the Publication Target where the Page is publishing to.

```cs
ICollection<PublishInfo> publishInfo = PublishEngine.GetPublishInfo(page);
foreach (PublishInfo info in publishInfo)
{
    info.PublicationTarget.Id
}
```

I'm trying to avoid the situation that if you publish a Page from the same CMS into Staging and Live and you are showing the Pages just if they are published or not. Also Pages published on Staging will appear in Live.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "the Publication Target were the Page is"? Also where are you using this code, is it at render time in a Template and what is it exactly for then?

Comment: What I mean is that if you are publishing a page to Live I need to know that the live Publication Target, but if I'm publishing to staging I need the Publication Target of staging.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In an Assembly Template Building Block you can determine the `RenderMode` and `PublishingContext` via the `engine`.

But before checking what Publication Target the current item is being published to, you need to know if you are actually being published, or if the render action of the Template is just a preview.

```cs
if (engine.RenderMode == RenderMode.Publish)
{
    PublicationTarget target = engine.PublishingContext.PublicationTarget;
}
```

From here onwards you can use `target.Id` or `target.Title` to check if it is your staging or live target that your item is being published to.

Comment: Hello Bart Koopman. Thanks for the quick answer. I tested it and it looks that works when I publish the page but I get an error with Template Builder, what is a pity because as you may now it is really usefull to debug Component Templates. Thanks

Comment: What error do you get in the Template Builder, the Template Builder should never pass the condition `engine.RenderMode == RenderMode.Publish`

Comment: Yes you are right. The problem is that I was trying to publish in the Template Builder debug log the Publication Target Id
_log.Debug("Publication Target Id:  " + this.engine.PublishingContext.PublicationTarget);
So that's why I got the error.
So there is any way to use this.engine.PublishingContext.PublicationTarget; without being in publishing time?
Really thanks in advance Bart

Comment: Since the Template Builder is rendering, there is no Publication Target, so you can obviously NOT use `engine.PublishingContext.PublicationTarget`, if you want to debug this code, you need to attach to the publisher service, and debug when actually publishing

Comment: Ok, Bart. Thanks for all your comments. It was really usefull